# Add Legend to ggplot in Python with geom_point

Tags: python, python-ggplot

I'd like to make a scatter plot in ggplot Python and control the layers (hence the two different geom_points. I can get my scatter to show nicely but I'd like to have a legend with 'yes' and 'no' with their corresponding colors.

Here's what I'm working with so far...

```
A = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]), ('C', ['yes', 'yes', 'no'])])

 ggplot(A, aes(x='A', y='B')) \
 + geom_point(data=A[A.C == 'yes'], color = 'blue') \
 + geom_point(data=A[A.C == 'no'], color = 'red')
```

This demonstrates the requisite plot, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the legend to show. I've tried various shape_colour_manual additions but haven't been able to figure it out.